# System identification of a resonant system

Tags: dynamical-systems, matlab, octave, system-identification

I want to write a matlab script that would identify a system from it's inputs and outputs. I have so far had good results with simple systems, but with this slightly more complex one I'm not able to arrive at the original equation. To do identification, I use a chirp signal and collect output data that covers a range of input frequencies. I then use arx() to estimate a transfer function from the input data.

My octave script is as follows:

```
pkg load signal
pkg load control

s = tf('s');

L = 0.1;
R = 80; 
C = 1e-4;

% Alt2: LC in series, resistor in parallel with output (LRC circuit)
%G = (s * L + 1 / (s * C)) / (R + s * L + 1 / (s * C));

% Alt1: simple RC circuit
G = 1 / (1 + R * C * s);

% simplify G
G = minreal(G)

% number of samples
N = 10000;

% frequency range in hz
Fstart = 15; Fend = 200;

t = linspace(0, 1, N);
sample_time = (t(end) - t(1)) / N

% generate stimulus signal and generate the output data from "real" system
stimulus = chirp(t, Fstart, t(end), Fend)';
[response, T, X] = lsim(G, stimulus, t);

%plot(t, stimulus, t, response, 'r');

% now try to go back to the original transfer function based on the collected data
[Gest, x0] = arx(iddata(response, stimulus, sample_time), 2);
Gest = minreal(d2c(Gest)); [b, a] = ss2tf(Gest); Gest = tf(b, a)

% compare the transfer functions
bode(G, Gest)

input("..");
```

If I run the script using simple transfer function (Alt1), I'm able to identify the original system precisely using arx (original transfer function G and estimated transfer function Gest are identical):

[image]

Short of an error from arx about matrix A being unstable the approximation is 100% accurate (error is due to the fact that I'm using second order approximation on a system Alt1 which is really a first order system so this is irrelevant. If I pass 1 as last argument to arx this error disappears).

However, if I try to do the same experiment with Alt2, which has a resonance at around 25Hz, the method fails:

[image]

The estimated transfer function is way off the target.

What is going on? Why am I not able to identify the second system using this method? Is it because I need more data around the resonance? How can I get an accurate estimate of the second system?

Comment: I tested this in matlab and I think your problem is that you did not increase the model order for Alt2.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen please test your suggestions before you post them. The original equation is second order so second order identification should suffice. I think the problem was that arx algorithm is simply not suitable for identifying a discontinuous model. I got the perfect result when I used moen4 instead.

Comment: ARX tries to fit $A(q)\,y(t)=B(q)\,u(t)+e(t)$. I am not sure what octave does when you only specify n, but when you use [arx(dat, 'na', na, 'nb', nb)](https://octave.sourceforge.io/control/function/arx.html) instead, with na the order of the A(q) polynomial and nb the order of the B(q) polynomial plus one with the constraint that nb<=na. For Alt2 the order of B(q) is two, so nb=3, which would also imply na=3 (but at least in matlab I was also able to use na=2 as well). So I would expect that arx(iddata(response, stimulus, sample_time), 'na', 2, 'nb', 3) would give the correct results.

Comment: Ah I see 'na', 2, 'nb', 3 worked. na = 3 did not work. The result is best so far with arx, but not a good fit as moen4 estimate. However, I'm confused. It says in docs for octave that following must be true: nb <= na yet I had to use nb = 3 and na = 2? It does make sense to me that the transfer function must be proper, however that would imply nb >= na instead.

Comment: I also do not know why. Maybe it meant to say the order of B(q)<=order of A(q), because otherwise the model would not be causal. But since you have all the data it is still possible to fit a noncausal filter.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem was that arx identification algorithm is just not suitable for solving discontinuous models. I changed algorithm to moen4 with same order and got the perfect solution.

[Gest, x0] = moen4(iddata(response, stimulus, sample_time), 2);

[image]